# About Restriction composition function to connected set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $h\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function such that $\{(x,h(x))\colon \ x\in C\}$ is connected for any connected $C\subset\Bbb R.$ Let $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a homeomorphism. Now, consider the function $h\circ f\colon \Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, I want to show that $\{(x,(h\circ f)(x))\colon x\in C\}$ is connected for any connected set $C\subset \Bbb R.$ I believe it would be correct since a homeomorphism behaves nicely with topological aspects. I tried to start by contradiction by assuming $$D=\{(x,(h\circ f)(x))\colon x\in C\}$$ is connected but I could not go further. Maybe there is another way to work around this problem. Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C \subset \Bbb R$ be connected. Then $f(C) \subset \Bbb R$ is connected as $f$ continuous and so by property of $h$
$$
\{(f(x), (h \circ f)(x)) : x \in C\} = \{(y, h(y)) : y \in f(C)\}
$$ is connected in $\Bbb R^2$. Now
$$
\langle f^{-1}, \text{id} \rangle : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2
$$ where $\text{id}(x) = x$, is continuous as $f^{-1}$ and $\text{id}$ are continuous so the image of our connected set above under $\langle f^{-1}, \text{id} \rangle$:
\begin{gather*}
\langle f^{-1}, \text{id}\rangle\Big(\{(f(x), (h \circ f)(x)) : x \in C\}\Big) \\
= \{(x, (h \circ f)(x)) : x \in C\}
\end{gather*} must be connected in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: OXLR, Thank you. you are right it is not complicated  but I went to wrong direction to prove it . Thank you.